# TikZ manual example won't compile

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried the following example from the `pgfmanual`, but it creates an error.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\tikz 
  \draw (2,0) coordinate (A) -- 
        (0,0) coordinate (B) -- 
        (1,1) coordinate (C)
        pic ["$\alpha$", draw, ->] {angle};

\end{document}
```

Error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \alpha 
l.10 pic ["$\alpha$", draw, ->]
                                {angle};
?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example requires two TikZ libraries: `angles` and `quotes`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \draw (2,0) coordinate (A) -- 
        (0,0) coordinate (B) -- 
        (1,1) coordinate (C)
        pic ["$\alpha$", draw, ->] {angle};
\end{document}
```